# Как спарсить url'ы на одной странице и затем зайти по каждому url'у и спарсить блок div

Tags: php, парсер, xmlparser, simple-html-dom

Есть [сайт](http://optnow.ru/opt.xml) с файлом .xml, в котором есть необходимые данные.

Необходимо спарсить все url, а затем пройти по каждому url'у и спарсить описание товара.

Вот так я вытаскиваю все url'ы:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$products = simplexml_load_file('http://www.optnow.ru/opt.xml');
foreach($products->shop->offers->offer as $product) {
    $productUrls[] = $product->url;
}
```

Теперь нужно пройти по каждому url'у. Пытался сделать так:

```
foreach($productUrls as $productUrl) {
    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $productUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $productDesc = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(str_get_html($productDesc)->find('.description  div div p'));
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Но на выходе появляется множество непонятных объектов

Comment: Что то странное ... если используется simple_html_dom.php, так и подгружать страницу стоит через него, а не через Curl, в этом скорее всего и проблема

Comment: Вот проблема была в том, что не получилось использовать file_get_html()

Comment: В данном случае у вас ничего не выйдет, поскольку str_get_html должна работать с объектом, который создается при использовании стандартной функции, а не тем что curl отдает, поэтому можно попробовать саму выдачу курла распарсить.

Comment: Причем в вашем случае даже регулярки не нужны